# Restrict data for google play services

Tags: background-data

Google play services consumes some data. Can I restrict data access to it. Does user experience compromised if I do. If yes what are they?

Comment: You might wish to see: [Google Play updates on mobile connection despite setting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75881/16575). My answer there should cover it completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict  apps from using data in several ways.

Android itself provides a built-in feature to restrict data for individual apps. It can be found at **Settings** → **Data Usage** → scroll down and select the app to restrict. You will find restrict background data option there. Select **Google Play Services** from there then restrict data.

As you mentioned that you need Google Play Services to be restricted, before going with this you should be aware about these.

- You cannot use Play Store with background data disabled, but you can still disable the automatic update feature in Google Play settings: go to **Settings** → **Accounts** → Disable sync.
- Turn off Google Maps offline caching in Maps settings.
- Use third-party apps like Onavo Count.

Comment: "You cannot use Play Store with background data disabled." → then I'm a magician. [I *do* use it that way](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/75896/16575). Works normal when connected to a WiFi network. However, you're correct when talking about *mobile data*: here it won't work anymore – but that's exactly what the OP wants, right?

Comment: On Android 8, Google Play Services ignores the setting; it racks up background data transfers even when disabled.

Comment: Same goes for android 7. Is there no way to stop the damn thing?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** forcibly restrict Google Play Services data consumption however it will impact the **'seamlessness'** of your android experience. Google Play Services are responsible for keeping your android in sync with numerous Google services that you and your device uses. 
 Google Play Service is a background service that helps to integrate several APIs like Location API, Maps API, Play Protect, etc. and limiting/disabling data access will impact these services. 
If you still want to proceed, you may use firewalls that work on non-rooted devices as well.